# Linux vhost kvm exit upon guest sending a packet

Tags: qemu, kvm, context-switch, hypervisor, virtio

According [deep-dive-virtio-networking-and-vhost-net](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/deep-dive-virtio-networking-and-vhost-net) a benefit of Vhost protocol (virtio-net guest driver & vhost-net host driver) is that when the Guest send a packet there is no need for the vCPU to stop executing.

My understanding is that a KVM exit is actually needed anyway since the associated vhost kernel thread in the Host has to process the packet sent. Perhaps the point made by the above link is that no kernelmode/usermode context switch is actually required (i.e. no need to resume QEMU process userspace context etc..)

Upon VM-exit to kvm from VMX non-root mode does the kvm kernel code run in the context of the VM associated's QEMU process ? Thank you.